# Trimmed GET var contains unprintable char

Tags: php, trim

I trim all a GET Var with `trim($var,'/ ')`.

Sometimes it still contains a unprintable char which is urlencoded: `%1C`

Where does this came from and how can i trim effectively all non printable chars from my get var?

I have the urldecoded Value, I use `urlencode` only to make the hidden char visible.

Comment: Urldecode first, trim second.

Comment: I't already urldecoded. Urlencoding the value is the only way to see that there is even a hidden char. I store them in the database and even with phpmyadmin there is no char. But when i urlencode it the char is visible. This was the fastest way to make it visible, buut i also could write a script which displays the char code.

Comment: Is the unwanted char always `%1C`?

Comment: `trim` removes whitespaces, not unprintable characters. Where is this data coming from, that it contains that char? Maybe you can sanitize it on the sending site?

Comment: @ZeissS: `trim` removes all character you want.

Comment: I don't know if it's always %1C, i even don't know if it's the actual char because maybe there is a charset problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `%1C` value in PHP is written as `\x1C`:

```
 trim($var, "/ \x1C");
```

See [PHP Manual: String -> Double quoted](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

For your scenario, you should as well look into [the filter extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php), it probably has good tools as well in it's chest for your scenario.

Answer (score -1):

first use **urldecode** function to decode the encoded value and then use **trim().**

Comment: I already have a urldecoded Value, i use urlencode only to make the hidden char visible.